# SQL Server VARCHAR length and value comparison

Tags: sql-server, varchar

Here are two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE INTKEYTBL 
(
    INTKEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   DUMMY_TEXT VARCHAR(2000) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE REFKEYTBL 
(
    REFID INT NOT NULL,
    REFKEY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    REF_TEXT VARCHAR(2000) NULL
)
```

Then, I need to get a `REFKEYTBL.REF_TEXT` with `INTKEYTBL.INTKEY` reference key.

```
SELECT REF_TEXT 
FROM REFKEYTBL
WHERE REFKEY IN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), INTKEY) 
                 FROM INTKEYTBL 
                 WHERE DUMMY_TEXT = 'DUMMY')
```

but there is no results in query.

I changed type at convert function `VARCHAR(15)` to `VARCHAR(20)`,

I can see any result in this query.

I wonder that why I should exactly set type and length for comparison each value?

Comment: Could you add sample data and expected result?

Comment: Why the RefKey field is not int or why is it varchar?

Comment: @AnupAgrawal 3rd party provided table, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If all text in REFKEYTBL.REFKEY is a number use this query:

```
Select REFKEYTBL.REF_TEXT FROM REFKEYTBL INNER JOIN INTKEYTBL 
ON Convert(INT,REFKEYTBL.REFKEY) = INTKEYTBL.INTKEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f96a/1

```
SELECT REF_TEXT 
FROM REFKEYTBL
WHERE REFKEY IN (SELECT CAST(INTKEY as VARCHAR(15)) 
                 FROM INTKEYTBL 
                 WHERE DUMMY_TEXT = 'DUMMY')
```